# PERC 5/i firmware on DELL PowerEdge 2950 cannot be updated

Tags: dell-poweredge, upgrade, dell-perc, firmware, dell-openmanage

My DELL PowerEdge 2950 (Windows Server 2008 R2) OpenManage shows this warning.

> Firmware version is out of date.
>   Firmware Version 5.0.2-0003
>   Minimum Required Firmware Version 5.2.2-0072

I installed this Windows update package from DELL. It shows installation successful.
Still the warning on the Server is same. I tried a reboot. But, of no use.

http://www.dell.com/support/home/us/en/19/Drivers/DriversDetails?driverId=WJG5R&fileId=2953936579&osCode=WNET&productCode=poweredge-2950&languageCode=EN&categoryId=SF

Comment: I think I remember that as being a bug in OMSA. Is OMSA at the latest version?

Answer (score 2):

Ran into the same issue. Seems to be a problem with the A08 version that is on Dell's site. Found following link to A09 file that worked for me.

http://www.dell.com/support/home/us/en/19/Drivers/DriversDetails?driverId=2RPK0&osCode=WS8R2&fileId=2974571956